# Novel about a military robot that goes rogue

Tags: story-identification

Trying to remember a book I read in the early 90s about a US military robot.
He's very advanced (an AI?) and being tested in a South American jungle (Venezuela maybe) when he goes rogue.
Pretty sure he was bright white but with camouflage capabilities.
He ends up in a small village and befriends a boy who lives there, he also helps the village by standing up to the local drug cartel/warlord/gang.

Comment: Sounds like a movie with Vin Diezel (or was that The Rock?)

Comment: @DVK - actually, I think there might have been a movie based on it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Solo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solo_%281996_film%29) was a very closely matching movie starring Mario Van Peebles, based on the novel ***[Weapon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapon_%28novel%29)*** by Robert Mason.

> The novel describes a new weapon system being developed for the US military; the titular Solo. A robot, Solo is designed to replace human soldiers in battle. It is humanoid in shape, in order to allow it to use all the military vehicles and equipment human soldiers do. Solo is capable of feats of great speed, strength and endurance.
>
> On another training mission Solo is lost; he is discovered by a group of Nicaraguan villagers who although initially fearful of him, come to trust the robot and depend on his protection. The novel details Solo's developing friendship with the villagers, whilst the US military attempts to recapture him.

Comment: That's it, I recognised the cover instantly! Thanks, I never knew there was a second novel, "Solo".